# Observable subscription - Ignore next method

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs, observable

I don't want to do anything on `next()` method, I want to handle `error()` and `complete()`.

This is my current solution that works well:

```
this.myService.myServiceObservable(params)
  .subscribe(
    () => {
      /**/
    },
    error => {
      // Handling errors here
    },
    () => {
      // Handling `complete()` here
    }
  );
```

I feel that this: `() => { /**/ }` is not the most elegant solution.

Anybody knows how to have the same result but not this ugly? Am I missing something?

Comment: Change `() => {` into `succes=> {` or use it for a succes message `{ console.log(succes); }`

Comment: That doesn't change. The complete is not the issue, is the next. I don't want to handle the next, but I can't remove it or it won't detect the error().

Comment: Sorry edited it a  little.

Comment: Is the same. I can put the name that I want. The thing is that has to have 3 handlers, 1 for next(), 1 for error() and 1 for complete(). I want to handle the last 2, but in order for reach them I need to do something in the first one, an empty comment is now doing the trick, but I don't like it.

Comment: Yeah that's how it works I use it for logging.

Comment: @Swoox If you want to ignore next(), how do you do it? You cannot remove it. And I don't want to console.log it.

Comment: So far I know you can't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `undefined` instead of a notification handler:

```
.subscribe(undefined,
  err => { ... },
  () => { ...}
);
```

Or you can pass so called "PartialObserver" object that has only handlers for the notifications you want:

```
.subscribe({
  error: err => { ... },
  complete: () => { ...}
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the second option looks quite elegant. :D